# Unity : How to get Random Time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, intervals

How do I create an object at random time intervals?
I gave "spawnInterval" a time interval with "Random.Range()" and put "spawnInterval" in "InvokeRepeating" and got an error.

It's part of my code...

```
private float startDelay = 2.0f;
private float spawnInterval = Random.Range(1.0f, 3.0f);
void Start()
{
  InvokeRepeating("Spawn", startDelay, spawnInterval);
}
void Spawn(){}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you're getting?

Comment: @Serlite
I got this -> UnityException: Range is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'Generator' on game object 'Generator'.
See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.
Generator..ctor () (at Assets/Scripts/Generator.cs:14)

Comment: Best way is to use a tick which is 100ns.  Timespan has properties like TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond and TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute.  So if you want a random timespan of 1 to 60 seconds your low limit is TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond and upper limit is 60 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond

Answer (score 1):

Forget `InvokeRepeating` and use delay time change.

```cs
private float startDelay = 2.0f;
private float spawnInterval;
void Start()
{
    Invoke("Spawn", startDelay);
}
void Spawn()
{
    spawnInterval = Random.Range(1f, 3f);

    Debug.Log($"Spawn time: {spawnInterval}");

    Invoke("Spawn", spawnInterval);
}
```

Comment: oh I should use Invoke() at times like this. I didn't know because I just started learning. Thank you for your help. It works without a problem.

Comment: @Glitt It is very good, but if you are looking for more optimized code with more flexibility, don't neglect `IEnumerator`.

Comment: Oh, ok I'll study that, too. Thanks for the additional advice.